# No battery percentage on Banana Pi with ampripper (/sys/class/power_supply is empty)

Tags: battery, bananapi

I built a cyberdeck using a Banana Pi M2 Zero and an Ampripper 3000 wired to a battery. I don't know if it's even possible but: how can I see the battery percentage? As I said, the /sys/class/power_supply/ directory is empty.

Comment: No. not possible.

Comment: @ChanganAuto alright, thanks. Can I know why?

Comment: Sure, the Ampripper 3000 like any other power bank acts like any other power supply. Laptops' batteries have electronics that inform the system about the charge and some other parameters and allow the OS to identify there's a battery connected. Power banks have nothing of that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto understood, thanks again!